# Have any of the "hard Brexit" Tories who voted against May's Withdrawal Agreement in late March stepped forward to be PM?

Tags: united-kingdom, conservative-party

Both Dominic Raab and Boris Johnson [voted for](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-47748806) May's Withdrawal Agreement (WA) on March 29 (after voting against on March 12.)

Did any of the "true hard" Brexiteers in the sense that they preferred a no-deal Brexit to the WA and voted against May's deal even on the 29th, put himself forward for the Conservative party leadership (and implicitly premiership) now that May has resigned?

Basically I'm looking for those Tories who meet the following three conditions simultaneously:

- declared themselves in favor of a no-deal Brexit
- voted against the WA on March 29 (and previously)
- has put him- or herself forward to be party leader now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The following people have [declared to stand](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-48395611):

> Michael Gove, Matt Hancock, Jeremy Hunt, Boris Johnson, Andrea Leadsom, Esther McVey, Dominic Raab, Rory Stewart, Sajid Javid, Mark Harper, James Cleverly, Kit Malthouse.

Based on [the voting record on the United Kingdom's withdrawal from the European Union on the 29th of March 2019](https://commonsvotes.digiminster.com/Divisions/Details/664#noes), we see none of the candidates above voted against this bill.

---

The aforementioned BBC article lists a number of people who are tipped to stand. Of those, the following people did vote against the bill as shown in [the link](https://commonsvotes.digiminster.com/Divisions/Details/664#noes):

> Priti Patel, Steve Baker

The BBC article has since been updated with a graph on how MPs voted:

[image]

Comment: The error is in the BBC article graphic, but the second vote should read 12 Mar.